# Latex: warning with caption

Tags: latex, caption

I'm using the following settings on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
 jmp,%
 amsmath,amssymb,
%preprint,%
 reprint,%
 nofootinbib,
 nobibnotes,
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
10pt
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx} % notazione \num{e-}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{curve2e}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{silence}
%\WarningFilter{caption}{Unsupported document class}
%\usepackage[center]{subfigure}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines
```

and I get the following warning:

```
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

The thing is that I've commented the caption package (it shouldn't be active anymore), trying to replace it with subcaption.

Is there a way to solve the warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`subcaption` automatically loads the `caption` package. The warning vanishes if you remove this package as well:

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
 jmp,%
 amsmath,amssymb,
%preprint,%
 reprint,%
 nofootinbib,
 nobibnotes,
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
10pt
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx} % notazione \num{e-}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{curve2e}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{silence}
%\WarningFilter{caption}{Unsupported document class}
%\usepackage[center]{subfigure}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines


\begin{document}
content...
\end{document}
```

Comment: But what if I need the subcaption package to draw captions for subfigure environment?

Comment: @PWillms Then either live with the warning or use a documentclass which is known to the caption package